# Why does the wording for the declaration of main change between draft standards?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

N3936 [basic.start.main]

> `2` An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a declared return type
>   of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An
>   implementation shall allow both
>
> — a function of `()` returning `int` and
>
> — a function of (`int`, pointer to pointer to `char`) returning `int`

N3337 [basic.start.main]

> `2` An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type
>   `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All
>   implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of
>   `main`:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ...  */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ...  */ }
> ```

What explains this change? The closest I can find is [DR 1669](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1669) in which the proposed wording already includes this change. We know that due to "array-to-pointer decay", that `char* argv[]` becomes `char** argv`.

```
std::cout << std::is_same<char**, std::decay<char*[]>::type>::value; // true
```

That doesn't really need rewording - it's self-explanatory. So why the change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just more flexible in general as it doesn't restrain the syntax.
The DR that introduces the change is [**#1003**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1003):

> The specification of the forms of the definition of `main` that an
>   implementation is required to accept is clear in C99 that the
>   parameter names and the exact syntactic form of the types can vary.
>   Although it is reasonable to assume that a C++ implementation would
>   accept a definition like
>
> ```
> int main(int foo, char** bar) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> instead of the canonical
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> it might be a good idea to clarify the intent using wording similar to
>   C99's.

The most common example is mentioned above:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

This isn't *guaranteed* to work according to C++11.

Another example are trailing-return-types. Consider that many people use them exclusively now - and write something along the lines of

```
auto main() -> int
```

We want these, and similar definitions, to be standard. Not implementation-defined.

Comment: Personally, I would not use trailing return-types where they don't buy me anything. But that looks like the reason.

Comment: Given that `auto main() -> int` and `int main()` are equivalent, and the old wording was already widely acknowledged as intending to allow equivalent definitions (`char**argv` in particular), I don't think this answer really explains it.

Comment: @hvd If it was widely acknowledged to be suboptimal wording... that would be a perfect reason to change it. And the DR confirms my reasoning.

Comment: @Columbo The reference to that DR was what was missing from your answer, and it clears it up: it wasn't because the old wording disallowed `char**argv`, it was that it wasn't clear from the old wording whether `char**argv` was allowed. Your answer claimed that the old wording disallowed equivalent declarations. I claim that the new wording merely clarifies what was already meant by the old wording.

Comment: @hvd: Related new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367400/how-does-implicit-return-0-tie-into-mains-return-type-deduction

Comment: @hvd I can't see how any revision of my answer implies that `char**` is disallowed.

Comment: @Columbo It's probably not worth getting into a discussion, since we probably do mean the same thing, but I read "`int main(int argv, char** argc)` [...] isn't guaranteed to work according to C++11" (in the current revision of your answer) as pretty much exactly that. If that's not what you meant, then it's fine.

Comment: @hvd I meant that the standard does not specify that it works: He specifies that an implementation can support it, and that the support would be compliant, but it would also be compliant to not support it. Assuredly we do mean the same thing. :)