# How does implicit return 0 tie into main's return type deduction?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

N3936 [basic.start.main]

> `2` An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a declared return type
>   of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An
>   implementation shall allow both
>
> — a function of `()` returning `int` and
>
> — a function of (`int`, pointer to pointer to `char`) returning `int`
>
> `5` A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the main
>   function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control
>   reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the
>   effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

[DR 1669](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1669) added the word **declared** to the wording, implying that if `main` were to be declared `auto`, a trailing return type is necessary. However, the wording introduced by [DR 1003](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1003) says, as in the quote above, that "an implementation shall allow both a function of ... returning `int` ... " This wording is a lot less strict when it comes to what the declaration of `main` should look like.

So, given the rules of `auto`, is an implicit `return 0;` enough to make

```
auto main() { }
```

legal?

Comment: The point of the defect report is to clarify this part of the standard. Asking about the meaning of the pre-DR standard is not useful, because the committee is already aware that the standard is not clear enough and will change it.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The changes already appear in N3936, though?

Comment: As @Sebastian said, keep in mind that later defect-reports correct (perceived) deficiencies in the standard (content *and/or* presentation), or bring it into line with new features. Alternatively, they might introduce new features, but that's not the case here. So, the later DR makes it unambiguous.

Comment: @2pacisstillalive I'm not sure what you mean. DR 1669 was in time to make it into C++14, that's why its status is listed as "C++14", isn't it? In other words, the C++14 standard has the word "declared", and `auto main() { }` is definitely not valid C++14.

Comment: @hvd OK I get it now :(

Comment: and related [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/3953764)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `auto main() { }` is not legal in C++14.

[dcl.spec.auto]

> `2` The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the
>   *decl-specifier-seq*, *type-specifier-seq*, *conversion-function-id*, or *trailing-return-type*, in any context where such a declarator is
>   valid. If the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type*
>   (8.3.5), that specifies the declared return type of the function. If
>   the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type,
>   the return type of the function is deduced from `return` statements in
>   the body of the function, if any.
>
> `10` If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder
>   type has no `return` statements, the `return` type is deduced as
>   though from a return statement with no operand at the closing brace of
>   the function body. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> auto  f() { } // OK, return type is void
> auto* g() { } // error, cannot deduce auto* from void()
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

This seems to imply that since there are no `return` statements, `main()` is deduced to be `void` and therefore the program is ill-formed. Yet, it leaves an ambiguity open that seems to allow the implicit `return 0` to be deduced to `int`. Oh well.